# How to define symbolic time series/ sequences?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

I need to check some equations involving operations on infinite length time series / sequences.

Say that I want to check the equation below:

[image: equation]

[image: equation]

I would like to define a time series filled with symbolic entries:

[image: equation]

Later on, I would define X[n] and then check the first equation.

Is this doable? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This brief attempt shows a flaw in your equation.

[image]

The expression equals zero because

```
X[b] = sum of x[k] from 0 to b, but for k > 0 x[k] = 0  ∴ X[b] = x0
```

likewise

```
X[a - 1] = x0
```

So `X[b] - X[a - 1] = 0`